# Get Grid Row and Grid column of button pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following buttons:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="48"></Button>
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="48"></Button>
```

Whenever pressed, these buttons will call:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

My question is how do I retrieve the column and row of the button that's been pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of [`RoutedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventhandler?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which is used for the `Click` event:

> `public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);`
>
> `sender` - The object where the event handler is attached.

Consequently, cast the `sender` parameter to `Button` and retrieve the row and column from the attached properties using its wrapper methods [`Grid.GetRow(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.getrow?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [`Grid.GetColumn(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.getcolumn?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var button = (Button)sender;
   var row = Grid.GetRow(button);
   var column = Grid.GetColumn(button);

   // ...other code.
}
```